# How to convert 0=..., 1=... columns, into 1 single column

Tags: r

I have been tasked to tidy up some data and am having issues with trying to transform the data from this format:

```
id occupation_busdriver   occupation_cashier   occupation_nurse
1   0                       0                    1
2   0                       1                    0
3   1                       0                    0
```

my actual dataset is significantly larger, but this is the area in which I am struggling, and therefore an example for this set would be much appreciated.

I have already tried using the gather and select functions

I am looking to have the data in this format:

```
id  occupation
1   nurse
2   cashier
3   busdriver
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455255/collapse-mulitple-columns-into-one-column-and-generate-an-index-variable

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please try something yourself first and let us know how it goes. Provide any code you've written in trying to accomplish this task in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the column index of the max value per row and based on the index, get the column names

```
data.frame(df1[1], occupation = sub(".*_", "", names(df1))[-1][max.col(df1[-1])])
#    id occupation
#1  1      nurse
#2  2    cashier
#3  3  busdriver
```

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to r and still do not quite understand, how to apply the above line to my own. Currently my column headers are id, year, gender, occupation_busdriver, occupation_cashier, occupation_nurse, income (in that order), thank you for your help and any further clarification would be much appreciated

Comment: @oliverg99 if you are interested in 'occupation' column, create an index of xolumns `nm1 <- grep('occupation", names(df1))` Instead of `[-1]` use `[nm1]`

Comment: After trying to implement this, when I run the programme, the console now shows a '+' and now nothing will run

Comment: @oliverg99  Did you meant `nm1 <- grep('occupation", names(df1))`  Probably, you missed a closing bracket or so

Comment: @oliverg99  sorry, there was a typo between `'` and `"`  Should be `nm1 <- grep('occupation', names(df1))` and then do `data.frame(df1[1], occupation = sub(".*_", "", names(df1))[nm1][max.col(df1[nm1])])`

Comment: @oliverg99  It is working for me now

Comment: Working for me too, thank you so much!